# What does the repoType argument refer to when obtaining a status badge for azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline, status

I'm trying to follow [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/badge/get%20build%20badge%20data?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) instructions

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/repos/{repoType}/badge?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

for getting an azure pipelines status badge on my github repository. Could somebody tell me what the repoType argument refers to? The instructions helpfully say that that its "the repository type" which literally tells me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess it is a field from [RepositoryTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.repositorytypes)

```
Bitbucket
Git
GitHub
GitHubEnterprise
Svn
TfsGit
TfsVersionControl
```